# How to convert .264 file to avi\wav using python

Tags: python-2.7, ffmpeg, h.264, video-processing, avi

Am trying to convert .264 files to mp4 or avi or wav format.

I have tried ffmpeg but no luck.

I am using python 2.7 on windows 7.

Please help!!

Comment: Please do a little research before posting !

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "no luck"? Can you show your code?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a .264 file I would suggest to wrap it in a mp4 container (no re-encode required that way).

Try the following:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.h264 -c:v copy OUTPUT.mp4
```

Moreover, .264 contains video only so there's no way you're gonna convert it to WAV which contains audio only.

Comment: .264 do contain audio content, I did this way convert .264 to .avi and .avi to .wav, I was successfull doing this, but for .264 to .avi I have used a GUI tool, where as I need to drive it from command line. Moreover, I tried your suggestion but it says "Invalid data found when processing input" -Thanks for the reply